# Having two forms in ASP.NET MVC 4 and posting one of them with ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application. I'm a beginner in web application. My problem is with file upload and ajax. I have two forms. One of the is for getting the data from user such as name, family and so more. The other one is to upload image. I want the user be able to upload the image before submitting the registration and also see the uploaded image in an `<img>` tag. Here is my code:

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Customer", FormMethod.Post))
{    
    <fieldset>         
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="controls">     
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Family</label>
            <div class="controls">                
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Family)                
            </div>
        </div>        
        <div class="control-group">            
            <div class="controls">        
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info"/>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </fieldset>
}

<img src="" class="img"/>
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadImage", "Customer", FormMethod.Post, new {      d="ImageUploadForm", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{            
    <input type="file" name="imgfile" class="imgfile"/>    
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btnUpload btn btn-info" />                   
}
```

**Action In Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public string UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase imgfile)
    {            
        string filePath = "";
        if (imgfile != null && imgfile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Customer/"), imgfile.FileName);
            imgfile.SaveAs(filePath);                
        }
        return "~/Customer/" + imgfile.FileName;
    }
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#ImageUploadForm').submit(function () {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                $('.img').attr('src', result);
            }
        })
        return false;
    }        
});
```

Now the problem is that when I select a file and hit the `Upload` button, the `UploadImage()` action is called and file is uploaded, but the success event of ajax is not called and it redirects me to another page called `localhost/Customer/UplaodImage` it's content is just the file path that `UploadImage` had returned. Is it ever possible to do this? Or I cant post a form data using ajax and not redirecting to another page? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I know, you cannot post a file through regular AJAX. Use some helper libraries: [FileUploader](http://github.com/valums/file-uploader), etc...

**UPDATE:**

By [Adeel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/154219/adeel) at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload) answer:

> With XHR2, File upload through AJAX is supported. E.g. through
>   [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) object, but unfortunately it is not supported by all/old
>   browsers.

Comment: The upload works fine and file is uploaded. The problem is that it redirects me to another page. I want to stay at the registration page.

Comment: That's because the request cannot be completed successfully! A request is called **success** only when you get a `200 (OK)` response. Believe me, I tried this a few years ago, you just get tired. Use a library. **FileUploader** is a good one.